# c++ Huge number notation

Tags: c++, syntax

Let's say i wrote

```
for (long long i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) {
    //std::cout << i<<"\n";
}
```

It's hard to tell what 10000000000 is, so is there a way to type it in like that or something

```
for (long long i = 0; i < 10,000,000,000; i++) {
        //std::cout << i<<"\n";
    }
```

So I could tell that it's 10 billion. I don't really need this right now, but I might, so I'm asking in advance :)

Comment: You can use the apostrophe as a digit separator to help readability: `10'000'000'000`